# I changed AspNetUsers to Users, but when I add new properies to ApplicationUser, they end up in AspNetUsers

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

In aspnet identity 2, I did this to remove the AspNet prefix of the identity tables:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

However, now if I try to do this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public Profile Profile { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

}
```

After I run Update-Database, There are no fields added in the Users table, but the AspNetUsers table is bck and has the FirstName and FullName fields:

[image]

How do I get these fields to be in the Users table..?

Comment: can you show your all of IdentityDbContext class, not just OnModelCreating?

Comment: You need also to map `ApplicationUser ` to the same table as `IdentityUser` by adding  `modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser >().ToTable("Users");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding "IdentityUser" 2 times. One here `:IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` and one here  `modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");`

Replace
`modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");`
 with `modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");`